# how to achieve C# struct behavior in java

Tags: java, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

As per MSDN standard struct is a value type, but java we cannot have struct so we can use class instead of struct. But my concern is to use the class instance as value type similar to C# struct. Can any one suggest me how to achieve the struct value type behavior in Java?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Demo d = new Demo("value", "name");
        demoTes(d);
        Console.WriteLine(d.Value);//prints "value" as output
        Console.WriteLine(d.TestValue);//prints "NameChanged" as output
    }
    public static void demoTes(Demo d)
    {
        d.Value = "Valuechanged";
        d.TestValue.Name = "Namechanged";
    }
}
public struct Demo
{
    public string Value;
    public Test TestValue;
    public Demo(string value, string name)
    {
        Value = value;
        TestValue = new Test(name);
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public string Name;
    public Test(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I need to pass my custom type as value not a reference to method.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sarath

Comment: You can't. The closest you can come is to create immutable classes, but that's not the same as them being value types. (It's not clear why you've used the pass-by-reference tag, as your question doesn't deal with pass-by-reference at all.)

Comment: I want to create custom value type similar to struct in C#. Can you suggest any other way to do?

Comment: No. Java simply doesn't support custom value types.